# Receiving DCF77 clock radio signal

Tags: rf, antenna

I scavenged a loop antenna from a meteo-station that gets synched from [DCF77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCF77) (77.5 kHz) clock signal. My idea was to implement a direct down-conversion with a microcontroller and decode the message based on the envelope.

As a first test, I connected the antenna to an oscilloscope. I was expecting a FFT peak @ 77.5kHz corresponding to the received signal from the radio station (the antenna should be tuned to this frequency)... But the only spikes that I can see are around 21.75 kHz.

If I don't see anything @ 77.5kHz with an oscilloscope, I strongly doubt to see anything with an uC ADC.

Am I missing something? Suggestions?

Thank you

[image: Loop Antenna]

[image]

Comment: You need to make a tuned tank circuit with high enough Q yet stable enough to stay on frequency within 0.2% . Without details on values, your test method will not achieve this.  with too much RF noise.  They use a XTAL to mix the signal down to baseband then AM demodulate.  Direct conversion is possible but requires more skill for tuner high Q and stability The signal can drop down in the low xx uV levels during the daytime.  If you have never designed a radio before, you may have a bit to learn

Comment: That probe is a "1X" probe, rather than "10X" probe? Probe + cable capacitance can de-tune that resonant antenna to a lower frequency. Try 10X probe. The bandwidth of that resonator can be quite narrow - resonant frequency should be carefully adjusted to 77.5 kHz. I've seen WWVB signal with this setup (at night) 2000 km range.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must remove all the trash around 77.5 kHz, emitted by all kinds of sources (like switching power supplies), or you will surely not see the DCF77 signal. The ferrite antenna does not filter anything by itself. Even when a sort of filter is formed by resonating the ferrite antenna to 77.5 kHz with a parallel capacitor, it does not have high enaough Q, so it is not narrow enough by itself (as a guess, perhaps 400 - 500 Hz at -6dB). That's why most DCF77 clocks use a 77.5 kHz crystal filter (bandwidth 5 - 15 Hz at -6 dB) to remove the noise. You will not see any DCF77 signal in the oscilloscope without good enough filtering, because the wideband trash is much stronger than the signal.
The filter's -6dB bandwidth must not be more than 100 Hz (centered at 77.500 kHz), but in many cases even 30 or 20 Hz bandwidth is required to receive the DCF77 signal.